# How do I add a reference to an assembly?

Tags: c#, mono, ikvm

I am trying to run some PDF to text C# code. I have references to 2 DLLs and I get this error when I try to run the program:

```
the type 'java.io.File' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.
You must add a reference to assembly 'IKVM.GNU.Classpath,
Version=0.20.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=13235d27fcbfff58'.
```

How do I add a reference to this assembly?

Comment: I am presuming that you are using Mono - I have re-tagged.

Comment: It's the use of IKVM that leads me to that assumption.

Comment: An update from Gold would obviously clear this up.

Comment: I didn't see the whole error message... on my screen the important bit scrolls off the end. I have edited the question so that people like me that have small screens can also read it. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you are using an assembly that has been generated from a JAR file using the [ikvmc](http://www.ikvm.net/userguide/ikvmc.html) compiler. You will need to reference the `IKVM.GNU.Classpath` assembly which is part of the [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/index.html) project. Right click on `References` and then `Add Reference...` and pick the `IKVM.GNU.Classpath.dll` file.